# How to round and only have 1 number after the decimal when using the text() widget in python

Tags: python

How do I only keep 1 number after the decimal when in situation like this :

```
lbl_recu.insert(END, f"\n\nElectricity:")
lbl_recu.insert(END, f"\n=====================================================")
lbl_recu.insert(END, f"\n-Normal Tariff 1000 @(0.098kWh/c) :\t\t {price}")
lbl_recu.insert(END, f"\n-Additional Tariff @ (+0.115c/kWh) :\t\t   {price2}")
lbl_recu.insert(END, f"\n-T.V.H :\t\t                        {tax}")
lbl_recu.insert(END, f"\n-Sub-Total :\t\t                      {total}")
lbl_recu.insert(END, f"\n\n====================================================")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use formaters like

```
{price:.1}
```

Price must be a float type